# Tomcat9: How do I configure IntelliJ to cleanly stop process on JMX port

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, process

I'm trying to use IntelliJ Idea to run some JSP applications. However, every time I stop and restart the Tomcat server, it throws an error saying the JMX port is already in use -

```
/Users/manishgiri/Documents/Software/Tomcat9/apache-tomcat-9.0.0.M22/bin/catalina.sh run
[2017-08-25 09:23:22,755] Artifact JSP-Servlets:war exploded: Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Error: Exception thrown by the agent : java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 9999; nested exception is: 
    java.net.BindException: Address already in use
Disconnected from server
```

This happens every single time, even if I switch the port numbers for the JMX port, which was `1099` by default -

[image]

The port `1099` also seems to be in use, when I stopped Tomcat 9 after the first run - 
[image]

How do I configure intellij to perform a clean shutdown of all processes, like Eclipse does? This behavior also happens on my Windows pc.

Comment: What happens if you don't specify the JMX port? Does it choose a random one, or not enable JMX? Also try setting 0.

Comment: Does the `shutdown.sh` script stop the server properly?